# Why do people put the same comment over and over again?

Tags: discussion, comments

I recently found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927883/android-default-activity-template-navigation-drawer) and the post only mentioned the error code. So at first, I commented on that question:

> Post your code in the question.

Then, why do other people write the same thing: "post your code, post your code."

I think it is the most repeated thing I have ever seen in a newly asked question.

People handle it, and why not make a rule for it?

Comment: There are only two comments which basically only say "post your code". And those were posted virtually at the same time, so that was simply a coincidence. The other two comments are trying to say more, even if they partially repeat the "post your code" line…

Comment: This happens because people post this comment simultaneously, and not all problems related to coding **actually contain code**

Comment: For once, all the comments on that post were nice and constructive. I actually want more of these.

Comment: @deceze see now I write solution on the comment then Why High Reputation User write the same thing .

Comment: You realize that the question in its first iteration looked like [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40927883/1)

Comment: Because this isn't a perfectly coordinated system in which every possible utterance can only be posted once. It's a bunch of people crowding around the same post coming to the same conclusions independently, not necessarily coordinating their timing with each other.

Comment: Comments aren't updating in realtime. It's perfectly possible that a user has been staring at the screen for a few minutes before posting their comment, not realising that somebody else has posted the same thing in the meantime.

Comment: @deceze comments are reasonably close to real time.

Comment: @Tiny Not if you don't reload the page/click the "more comments" link…

Comment: Well, yeah... you are notified of comments in real time, whether or not you view them is a different matter regardless of whether it is shown immediately or not.

Comment: Well, yeah... you are notified of comments in real time, whether or not you view them is a different matter regardless of whether it is shown immediately or not.

Comment: So tempted to upvote only one of you guys' comments to throw the other into an existential crisis

Answer (score 13):

In the [first version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40927883/1), only a few sentences and a stack trace was included. Questions like those are off-topic:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

So the comments are constructive; IMHO the question now contains too much code but at least it could be answered. (It has been closed now because it doesn't satisfy the M in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).) It doesn't matter if one, two or three users commented something along the lines of "please post your code"; you can flag those comments as obsolete as soon as the OP posts his code. Sometimes users do delete the comment themselves when somebody else just posted more or less the same, but not always.